# Every polytope is orthogonal projection of some regular simplex

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics

I have a statement and I am unable to prove it. Can you help me please?

> Prove that every polytope $P \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is an orthogonal projection of some $k$-dimensional regular simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$
>   for suitable $k$, $n$.
>
> (An orthogonal projection
>   is a mapping $\pi$ from the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a subspace $M\cong\mathbb{R}^d$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ the vector $\pi(x) − x$ is orthogonal to $M$. A simplex
>   is regular if all its edges have the same length.)

Comment: Nice question. You should really consider editing your question with some [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) : $\mathbb{R}^n$ looks better than R n.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc.) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or talking over your head. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Since comments are easily overlooked, [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3472653/edit) to add details.

Comment: According to [this paper (no paywall)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00147736), only polytopes with "central symmetry" are realized as projections of an orthogonal simplex.

Comment: Note that orthogonal *projection* preserves convexity of a simplex (though not necessarily its "regularity" as you've defined it, all edge lengths equal).  So the polytopes that could be realized in this fashion are [necessarily restricted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope).

Comment: @MikeEarnest That can't be right. Not even the simplex itself is centrally symmetric (but trivially a projection of itself). Ccentrally symmetric polytopes are exactly the projections of *cross polytopes*, which is also close to what the linked paper states in its abstract (I have not read the paper itself).

Comment: You can check my recent answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407139/maximum-vertex-amount-of-low-dimensional-simplex-projection/407161?noredirect=1#comment1044178_407161) to see why every polytope is the orthogonal projection of *some* simplex. Similarly, every simplex is the orthogonal projection of a regular simplex with the same number of vertices embedded into a sufficiently large dimension.